# Is this a good question? - What is a dungeon crawl?

Tags: discussion, questions

**From these comments, I want to ask "What is a dungeon crawl?", but does it feel worthy enough?:**

---

> I would add the concept of the dungeon crawl where a band of diverse adventurers (wizard, fighter, elf, etc.) battle monsters in an underground setting, including a final boss monster, is straight out of the Mines of Moria from J. R. R. Tolkien's The Fellowship of the Ring. –  RobertF 1 hour ago

---

> RobertF: I think that point is worthy of its own question about "what is a dungeon crawl" ... I don't know if that particular scene is linked to where "dungeon" comes from. I agree that the template parallel looks obvious. –  KorvinStarmast 56 mins ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a [terminology](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag: its presence indicates that terminology questions are generally on-topic. Ask away.

---

Aside, using meta to get pre-approval for every question will very quickly meet with *dis*approval of that use of meta. Just ask your questions and find out if they're considered good the normal way, via people's comments, up/down votes, and close votes or lack thereof.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have "not worthy" for a downvote or close reason, so that's a question not worth asking. It's worthy if it's worth it to you.

We do have "no research effort" for a downvote reason though, so make sure you do some googling and independent research first and come back to us if you're still not clear.

And like SevenSidedDie said — don't overuse meta to pre-approve your questions. So far you've given us just the bare bones of questions we can't actually judge the quality of. I suggest you just go and ask first, and come to meta if you have significant trouble. We can help you if you're sure it would be a problem and need some assistance judging how (or whether) to ask it, If you're only worried about whether it's "worthy" just skip straight to finding out by asking it. (But do your research first.)

Answer (score -1):

My dear, incorrigible Malandy :-)

I searched and found about seventeen pages of RPG.SE questions that appear to include reference to, in passing or otherwise, dungeon crawl or dungeon crawling.  The term is imbedded in the hobby, from the get go.   Neologisms eventually take root and become a commonly used term.

(As a comparison:

1. think about how quickly "Radar" became a word that began as a bit of tech speak for Radio Detection and Ranging.
2. Scuba was once an acronym for "Self Contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus" but eventually that acronym became its own term/word).

It is common usage, so maybe we'll need to ask @RobertF to elaborate on refining the question to address the [Trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DungeonCrawling) involved: mixed party, underground adventure, and the Big Bad Boss at the end!  That is because the hobby has grown immensely to the point that dungeon crawl has become a sub set of a whole lot of different RPG adventure styles, both in Table Top form and in Video Game Form.